# How to remove background: transparent?

Tags: css, leaflet

[image]

leaflet popup close button is not displayed. But, when I uncheck `background: transparent;` the close button is displayed. I already tried `background: unset;`, but it doesn't work. How can I remove  `background: transparent;`?

The code below is from https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css

```
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 18px;
    height: 14px;
    font: 16px/14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #c3c3c3;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: As per Stack Overflow, **do not** share images of code. Instead, use snippets to add your code as formatted text.

Comment: Thank you. I just removed the image and wrote the code.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and OP should be looking instead for https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-closebutton

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the css

```
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button {
   background: yourOwnColor / url;
}
```

If you want to avoid global change then wrap up the component with a div and set a flag `class` to it.

```
.yourFlagClass .leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button {
   background: yourOwnColor / url;
}
```